# .NET flaw with string to byte[] conversion?

Tags: .net, string, arrays

I experienced an issue retrieving encrypted data from an NVARCHAR field in our SQL Server (2008R2) database where it appears that for some records, the string value of the data in my C# .NET application is different to that in the database record. This was kind of hard to prove but i eventually found that by looking at the byte[] representation of the strings that there were indeed differences.

Playing around further I was able to produce this test application that has me a little concerned. I took a byte array (converted from hex for simplicity of setup), converted it to a string with the Unicode encoder and back to a byte array and saw that the resulting byte array was different to the original one! In the below code, the first hex string fails while the second works.

Is there something wrong with my method here (and i don't mean by trying to convert byte arrays to strings) or is there potentially something wrong in the .NET framework?

```
using System;

namespace ByteArrayTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WindowWidth = 80;
            Console.Clear();

            foreach (string s in new string[]
                {
                    "00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000AB4CB23EBE32F0DD",
                    "00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000E12617F83C3F7F6A"
                }
            )
            {
                byte[] b1 = System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary.Parse(s).Value;
                string tmp = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b1);

                byte[] b2 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tmp);

                Console.WriteLine("Orig: {0}", s);

                string s2 = BitConverter.ToString(b2).Replace("-", "");
                Console.WriteLine("Conv: {0}", s2);

                Console.WriteLine(s == s2 ? "EQUAL :-)" : "** NOT EQUAL **");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using VS2010 and tested this under .NET frameworks 4 and 3.5 and the results of this are:

```
Orig: 00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000AB4CB23EBE32F0DD
Conv: 00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000AB4CB23EBE32FDFF
** NOT EQUAL **

Orig: 00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000E12617F83C3F7F6A
Conv: 00CD6C8300C2A2C09B9E6B1F258F7B1101000000E12617F83C3F7F6A
EQUAL :-)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to store arbitrary opaque binary data which isn't *really* text in an NVARCHAR field, you should use base64 encoding to encode it. Trying to just treat it as text encoding in UTF-16 (which is what you're doing here) is a fundamentally bad idea, and very likely to lose data. As *one* example of where this could happen, you could end up with a string which contains *half* of a [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2#Code_points_U.2B10000..U.2B10FFFF) without the other half.

I assume your "encrypted data" *was* stored by just calling `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)` where `bytes` is the encrypted data? If so, that's definitely not the way to go. Use:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

instead, and when retrieving the data, use

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

Alternatively, use a database field which is designed for binary data in the first place.

EDIT: (Copied from my comment) The example you've given is failing at the end, converting U+DDF0 to U+FFFD. That's actually exactly the scenario I mentioned above - U+DDF0 is a "low surrogate", but it doesn't have a corresponding "high surrogate", so Encoding.GetString is converted that character into U+FFFD, which is the "replacement character", which is (from the [Unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf))

> used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode

IIRC, you can specify what `Encoding` does when it encounters bad binary data (which is effectively what you're giving it) and potentially make it throw an exception instead.

Comment: "Alternatively, use a database field which is designed for binary data in the first place." - sounds like good advice!

Comment: Thanks Jon, Yes we are realising that the database fields for holding encrypted data should probably be VARBINARY types instead, but having said that, I guess i'm wondering more about the specific example i posted above.

Comment: @Mitch: There are times where using a string representation makes life easier - it's simple to cut and paste, for example. But yes, making the storage reflect what you're trying to store is usually a good plan :)

Comment: @MattA: I'm not on a machine with .NET installed at the moment, so I can't easily tell. If you could cut down the example to *one* data sample, ideally a smaller one (initialized as a straight byte array to make it even easier to test under something like ideone.com) that would help.

Comment: @MattA: I've just tried your test under ideone.com, and it showed EQUAL twice. What does it show on your machine?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: sure, but text-readable encrypted data doesn't sound that useful :)

Comment: @Mitch: Ever received a licence key by email? :)

Comment: @Jon: I usually copy/paste these into some sort of application :) but I take your point. +1

Comment: Updated original post with results from test app.

Comment: @MattA: Thanks. Okay, so it's failing with U+DDF0, converting it to U+FFFD. That's actually exactly the scenario I mentioned - U+DDF0 is a "low surrogate", but it doesn't have a corresponding "high surrogate", so Encoding.GetString is converted that character into U+FFFD, which is the "replacement character", used for unknown or invalid values.